# Помогите с Nested вьюхами

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Создаю приложение на Rails по доставке обедов с ежедневным меню.

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20171226222308) do

  # These are extensions that must be enabled in order to support this database
  enable_extension "plpgsql"

  create_table "categorys", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
  end

  create_table "items", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.decimal "price"
    t.bigint "category_id"
    t.string "image_url"
    t.bigint "weekday_id"
    t.index ["category_id"], name: "index_items_on_category_id"
    t.index ["weekday_id"], name: "index_items_on_weekday_id"
  end

  create_table "weekdays", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.date "dateday"
  end

  add_foreign_key "items", "categorys"
  add_foreign_key "items", "weekdays"
end
```

Имеются  модели:

```
class Weekday < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :items, dependent: :destroy
end

class Item < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :weekday
  validates :name, :price, presence: true
end

class Category < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :items
  def to_s
      name
  end
end
```

Контроллер:

```
class WeekdaysController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_weekday, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  def show
    @category = Category.all
    if params[:category_id].present?
    @current_category = Category.find(params[:category_id])
  end
...
```

Представления `Weekday` и `show.html.erb`:

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <strong>Name:</strong>
  <%= @weekday.name %>
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Dateday:</strong>
  <%= @weekday.dateday %>
</p>

<h1>Menu </h1>
<div class="btn-group">
    <% @category.each do |category| %>
    <%= link_to category.name, weekday_path(category_id: category.id),
     class: "btn #{params[:category_id] == category.id.to_s ? 'btn-primary' : 'btn-secondary'}"%>
    <% end %> 
</div>

<% if @current_category %>
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>price</th>
                <th>image</th>
                <th></th>
                <th></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>  
        <div class="tbody">
                <% @current_category.items.each do |item| %> 
                <tr>
                    <td><%= item.name %></td>
                    <td><%= number_to_currency item.price %></td>
                    <td><%= image_tag item.image_url %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to "Edit",
                         edit_weekday_item_path(weekday_id: @weekday.id,id: item.id) %></td>
                    <td><%= link_to "Delete", [@weekday, item], method: :delete, conform:
                        "Srly?"%></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
        </div>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <% else %>
    <div class="alert alert-info"> PLS select a course PLS</div>
<% end %>



<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_weekday_path(@weekday) %> 
<%= link_to 'Back', weekdays_path %>

<%= link_to  "Add new item", new_weekday_item_path(@weekday)%>
```

При переходе в `Weekday` должно выводить `Items`, принадлежащие данному дню и находящисхя в определенной `Navs, Category - (First,Second, Drink)`. На данный момент в `Navs` выводиться `Items` принадлежащие  `Category`, но без проверки на принадлежность к `Weekday`.

Как сделать эту проверку, чтобы в определенной категории выводились `Items` принадлежащие определенному `Weekday` и `Category`? Иными словами, как вывести модель `Item` которая принадлежит одновременно двум не связанным моделям?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно поняла задачу, то здесь стоит воспользоваться scope. Нужно вывести items с определёнными `category_id` и `weekday_id`

```
scope :by_category, ->(category_id) { where(category_id: category_id) }
scope :by_weekday, ->(weekday_id) { where(weekday_id: weekday_id) }
```

Поместив этот код в модели Item вы сможете выбрать нужные итемы, например в контроллере:

```
@items = Item.by_category(params[:category_id]).by_weekday(params[:weekday_id])
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, из-за небольшого опыта разработки, не знал про такие вещи. Еще раз, спасибо!!!

Comment: @ВладимирКонцеропятов, я рада, что всё заработало :) 
Подробнее про scopes можно почитать [здесь](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes)